# Binning/Group numbers in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python so apologies for what I hope is a simple question.  I have data loaded into a pandas data frame.  One of the columns is a dollar amount(PAYMENT_AMOUNT).  I would create a new column and bin/group similar ranges.  If I were to do this in SQL I would use the below case statement.  Is there a similar function in Python?

```
(
          CASE
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '0' AND '9.99'
            THEN '0-9.99'
           WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '10' AND '19.99'
            THEN '10-19.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '20' AND '39.99'
            THEN '20-39.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '40' AND '59.99'
            THEN '40-59.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '60' AND '79.99'
            THEN '60-79.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '80' AND '99.99'
            THEN '80-99.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '100' AND '149.99'
            THEN '100-149.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '150' AND '299.99'
            THEN '150-299.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT BETWEEN '300' AND '499.99'
            THEN '300-499.99'
            WHEN PAYMENT_AMOUNT >= '500'
            THEN '500+'
            ELSE 'other'
          END) USD_BIN
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: Python `if-elif-else` statements can be used to do the same thing. Did you have a look at that?

Comment: Python does not have a CASE statement. You can use multiple if else block or implement switcher as described here https://bytebaker.com/2008/11/03/switch-case-statement-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

```
def binning(bin):
    if bin < 10:
        return '0-9.99'
    if 10 <= bin < 20:
        return '10-19.99'
    if 20 <= bin < 40:
        return '20-39.99'
    if 40 <= bin < 60:
        return '40-59.99'
    if 60 <= bin < 80:
        return '60-79.99'
    if 80 <= bin < 100:
        return '80-99.99'
    if 100 <= bin < 150:
        return '100-149.99'
    if 150 <= bin < 300:
        return '150-299.99'
    if 300 <= bin < 500:
        return '300-499.99'
    if bin >= 500:
        return '500+'
    else:
        return 'other'
```

vfunc = np.vectorize(binning)

df['column_name'] = vfunc(df['payment_amount'])